# Can websites using CSS be correctly shown in feature phones?

Tags: html, mobile-website

I was wondering if the html tag:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/style.css">
```

Can the stylesheet be loaded correctly on feature phones?

Comment: what do you mean by shown?  will the stylesheet be loaded?

Comment: Depends on what is in the stylesheet, which phone you are talking about, which browser you are using (I used a third party browser on my last feature phone) and what your definition of "correctly" is.

Comment: There are literally thousands of feature phones with varying levels of (usually terrible) CSS support. Also, "feature phone" implies oldschool flip phone without a native browser. Do you mean that, or "Smartphone" (e.g. iPhone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Quentin says, it depends on what's in the stylesheet. Feature / dumb phones have varying CSS support, so you'd need to do a bit of research. Something to get you started:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Web/#!nokia-browsers/symbian-browsers/css-3-support.html

A list of CSS3 properties Nokia's Symbian browser can support. Sure there's a lot more stuff like this floating around. 
If you didn't already know, Symbian's an OS used on phones such as the N95 (last non-smartphone I owned)

Unfortunately stuff like media queries that you'd use for modern responsive design are often pretty shaky on these platforms from my experience.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Symbian is a smartphone OS, and the N95 was marketed as a smartphone (even if it is pretty dumb by today's standards). A feature phone would have far fewer features.